# Automatically shrink desktop when turning of screen in a multi monitor set up

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, desktop, windows-11, multiple-desktop

I wonder if this can be done, maybe with the help of some 3rd party application or so. I'm on Windows 11; recently I have been moving from a two-monitor setup up to a three one and finally to a fourth one. But I'm not always doing the sort of work that really can take advantage of so many monitors, so often I end up turning off one or two, always one on each side.

The desktop is extended to make use of every monitor, so even if turned off, the desktop is still available "under" the black screens.

To prevent stuff going there without having to, windows I can't find because they are there, or messing up things clicking on things I sbouldn't, or the mouse pointer getting lost in these areas, it would be nice that the desktop itself "shrinked" on its own when turning off those monitors. It can be done manually, but is such a hassle that I don't bother, as I'd have to manually change it again when I switched on the monitors. And as Windows seems to detect when a screen is "on" or "off", for sure this could be done programatically.

The same applies, of course, about automatically "expanding" the Windows desktop when the monitor is "available" again.

Any ideas??

Comment: If your monitors are connected through DP or DVI-D, windows should automatically uninstall the desktops when they are turned off, doing what you seek. If that is not desired you can go for the approach I use. I use ActualTools Window Manager. I have setup profiles that have specific monitors connected and using a hotkey I switch between profiles. Once a profile is active, the monitor will go into standby automatically, turning off by itself.

Comment: So nice! I didn't notice that behaviour on Windows, even my monitors are connected through DP, DVI-D and HDMI (I don't know if the behaviour you describe applies to that one, also). But in case it doesn't, and also for the sake of my remaining analog VGA monitor, I'll try that Window Manager later. Thank you!

Comment: HDMI may or may not work, depends on the version of HDMI. My TV uses HDMI and even with a HDMI 2.0 cable, it doesn't detect the tv being on or off. And also Analog VGA (SUB-D) does definitely not do this, and neither does DVI-I (basically all analog kinds don't, and HDMI can transmit as analog.